# Detect condition between pairs of entries on a Python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Let's say I've a list:

```
ls = [1,2,4,3,6,18,10,60,70,40]
```

that I want to change to:

```
ls = [1,2,4,3,6,18,10,None,None,40]
```

**because:**

---

1) There is a value in index "x+1" that is **greater than 5 times** than the value in index "x".

(**index 7: 60**, is bigger than **index 6: 10** multiplied by **5**)

---

2) The next value in index "x+2" is **also greater than 5 times** than the value in index "x"

(**index 8: 70**, is bigger than **index 6: 10** multiplied by **5**)

---

3) The value in index "x+3" **isn't greater** than the value in index "x"

(**index 9: 40**, isn't bigger than **index 6: 10** multiplied by **5**)

---

4) The two values of the indexes **between the right condition** ("x+1" and "x+2") will be **replaced by None** between the two "limits" ("x" and "x+3") that matched the condition, thus **setting "x+1" and "x+2" as None**.

Note that the condition now is not between two consecutive indexes...

---

### Edited with example code:

This is what i've tried, although it seems "too much"...

```
ls = [1,2,4,3,6,18,10,60,70,40]

for i in range (1,len(ls)-1):   
    if ls[i-1] == None:
        # another for to get previous results????
        for o in range(0,i):
            if ls[o] != None:
                lastGood = ls[o]
    else:
        if ls[i] > ls[i-1]*5:
            ls[i] = None
        else:
            lastGood = ls[i-1]

        if ls[i] < ls[i-1]/5:
            ls[i] = None
        else:
            lastGood = ls[i-1]



    if ls[i] > lastGood*5:
        ls[i] = None

    if ls[i] < lastGood/5:
        ls[i] = None



print ls
```

--

```
output: [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 18, 10, None, None, 40]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've just described a problem - what's your question, exactly?

Comment: What code have you attempted? Are you seeing any errors? Please ask a question after you have attempted something, StackOverflow users are not here to write code for you.

Comment: I've updated my question with my own code. I think I've used too many "for" iterations as well as double check if conditions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to agree the code you've written is a little much for your required purpose. I managed to truncate it a little bit, does this solve your issue?

```
lastGoodIndex = 0
for i in range(len(ls) - 1):
    if ls[i] == None:
        if ls[i+1] > ls[lastGoodIndex]*5:
            ls[i+1] = None
    elif ls[i+1] > ls[i]*5:
        ls[i+1] = None
        lastGoodIndex = i
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the good solution found by BadKarma, I've also another possible answer that I found by myself after digging for a long long time:

```
import bisect
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for entry in range(1,len(ls)+1):
    startNone = [next(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(ls), key=itemgetter(1)) if key == None]
    endNone = [next(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(reversed(ls)), key=itemgetter(1)) if key == None]
    if len(startNone)>0: 
        if entry-1 > len(ls)-endNone[0][0]:
            bigger = ls[entry-2]*5
        else:
            bigger = ls[startNone[-1][0]-1]*5
    else:
        bigger = ls[entry-2]*5
    seek = ls[0:entry]
    i = bisect.bisect_left(seek, bigger)
    if i<entry:
        ls[entry-1] = None
```